# Python subprocess launch Android virtual device but can't terminate and get wrong PID

Tags: android, python, windows, subprocess, android-virtual-device

I need launch Android virtual device with python, here is my code:

```
command = "emulator @device_name"
emulator_process = subprocess.Popen(command)
```

and I need to terminated emulator, I try:

```
emulator_process.terminate()
```

and

```
emulator_process.kill()
```

and kill with pid:

```
command = "taskkill /f /PID " + str(emulator_process.pid)
os.system(command)
```

it return success kill task but emulator still execute.

how can I terminate emulator correctly?

---

UPDATE:

and now I try kill by task name:

```
command = "taskkill /IM qemu-system-i386.exe"
os.system(command)
```

it kill task with other pid, not emulator_process.pid.

Why emulator_process.pid get different pid?